Unexpected Git incoming/outgoing conflict in Visual Studio Code
I develop an app using Visual Studio Code on my computer, and I use the Source Control function to sync the code on a GitHub account.
I've never had any issue using the basic functions: I commit my changes, and then I Sync, and then the code is on my GitHub project, and that's fine.
Today, something very strange happens: I cannot sync my last commit, I've got error messages talking about unfinished merge, incoming/outgoing conflicts etc.
In the Source Control window, I see 2 different versions of my code: a so called "Incoming change" (that is basically the last changes I have committed and synced a few days ago) and a so called "Outgoing change", where I recognized the most recent code I have lately commited:

I've tried all the suggested options (fetch, push, pull...) but nothing happens, I always get an error message saying that "A merge is unfinished - MERGE HEAD existing".
What is happening here?

Back up the versions of files you want to keep. Maybe just copy one. Open the terminal, enter the repository path and run git status. It should report something about an unfinished merge. You can run git merge --abort to abort the unfinished merge and try git pull again. If git pull complains about conflicts, you need to resolve them.

Your suggestion has worked perfectly. I just had to do additional merge changes manually, but at the end I have succeeded. Thank you !

Another option is to open the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and type:
Git: Abort Merge

ElpieKay's solution worked: the solution was the git merge --abort command.
